# Orbeon in Ubuntu - Cant connect to SQL Server

Tags: orbeon

I was working orbeon in windows os by establishing connection with SQL server. Now I changed the os to ubuntu, but couldn't establish the sql connection. Installed jTDs driver too.

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container" 
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" 
          description="User database that can be updated and savedfactory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" 
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />



       <Resource name="jdbc/sqlserver" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 

        initialSize="3" maxActive="10" maxIdle="10" maxWait="30000" poolPreparedStatements="true" validationQuery="select 1" 

        testOnBorrow="true" username="sa" password="speridian1" url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.40.22:1433;databasename=orbeon;user=sa;password=speridian1"/>
```

```
            initialSize="3" maxActive="10" maxIdle="10" maxWait="30000" poolPreparedStatements="true" validationQuery="select 1" 

            testOnBorrow="true" username="sa" password="speridian1" 

            url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.40.22:1433;databasename=solismammotest;user=sa;password=speridian1"/>
```

Anybody plz tell how I can connect it to the sql server

Comment: Since this question was [cross-posted on the Orbeon Forms forum](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Orbeon-in-Ubuntu-Cant-connect-to-SQL-Server-td4662653.html), and Erik already answered there, I suggest you continue the discussion there, and we can then post a final answer here as needed.

Comment: I placed JDBC driver, but the version was 41. when I placed JDBC 42 it works fine for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved by the poster by upgrading the SQL Server JDBC driver from version 41 to version 42.